# Как можно произвольно раскидат объекты относительно таргета Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сейчас использую такой способ при старте спавню объект и даю ему позицию в рандоме, но есть минум они бывают спавняться очень близко  друг  к другу

```
for (int j = 0; j < Systemplanet.childCount; j++)
{
    int Done = Random.Range(0, CreateRandom.Length);
    MyDepoSits = RandomCategoriesAsteroid(8, CreateRandom[Done]._Rich, CreateRandom[Done]._Average, CreateRandom[Done]._Poor);
    for (int i = 0; i < MyDepoSits.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject item = Instantiate(PrefabItem);
        item.transform.SetParent(Systemplanet.GetChild(j));
        item.GetComponent<Asteroid>().target = Systemplanet.GetChild(j);
        item.transform.position = Systemplanet.GetChild(j).position;
        item.transform.position += new Vector3(Random.Range(-i / 4.4f, .5f), Random.Range(-i / 4.4f, .5f), Random.Range(-i / 4.4f, 2f));
        item.transform.FindChild("Header").GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = MyDepoSits[i];
        item.SetActive(false);
        //CanvasChild.GetChild(i).GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = MyDepoSits[i];
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут надо только экспериментировать.
Я бы рекомендовал всё, что связано с рандомам заносить в отдельные переменные, и дебажить через Unity в Рантайме.

В вашем случае, надо просто увеличить минимальную, возможную координату:

```
public float min = 4.8f;
public float max = 5f;

public float minZ = 4.8f;
public float maxZ = 2f;


 for (int j = 0; j < Systemplanet.childCount; j++)
{
    int Done = Random.Range(0, CreateRandom.Length);
    MyDepoSits = RandomCategoriesAsteroid(8, CreateRandom[Done]._Rich, CreateRandom[Done]._Average, CreateRandom[Done]._Poor);
    for (int i = 0; i < MyDepoSits.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject item = Instantiate(PrefabItem);
        item.transform.SetParent(Systemplanet.GetChild(j));
        item.GetComponent<Asteroid>().target = Systemplanet.GetChild(j);
        item.transform.position = Systemplanet.GetChild(j).position;
        item.transform.position += new Vector3(Random.Range(-i / min, max), Random.Range(-i / min, max), Random.Range(-i / minZ, maxZ));
        item.transform.FindChild("Header").GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = MyDepoSits[i];
        item.SetActive(false);
        //CanvasChild.GetChild(i).GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = MyDepoSits[i];
    }
}
```

В данном случае, я поставил уже значения, с помощью который, объекты будут спавниться дальше. Но всё же, рекомендую тестировать в ран тайме